# Reverse engineering algebra question - why is it not working?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

So I have the curve $y=(x-4)(x-2)(x+1) = x^3 -5x^2 + 2x + 8$.

Note here [$\int_{-1}^0 y dx = \frac{61}{20}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%20(x-4)(x-2)(x%2B1)%20from%20-1%20to%200).

The question I propose to create is as follows:

> A curve has the equation $y=f(x)$, where $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 8$, where $a, b$ are constants. The curve meets the $x$ axis at $(-1, 0)$ and the integral $\int_{-1}^0 f(x) dx = \frac{61}{20}$.

If all checks out, they should get $a=-5$ and $b=2$.

But this is not the case.

$(-1, 0)$ being a point on the curve gives $b-a = 7$.

The integral condition gives [$a/3 - b/2 + 47/10 = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(integral%20of%20x%5E3%20%2B%20ax%5E2%20%2B%20bx%20%2B%208%20from%20-1%20to%200)%20%3D%2061%2F20).

These two simultaneous equations do not give $a=-5$ and $b=2$.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is wrong. $\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx=\frac{61}{12}$, not $\frac{61}{20}$. Therefore, the second equation should actually be $\frac{a}{3}-\frac{b}{2}=-\frac{32}{12}$, which does indeed give $a=-5$ and $b=2$.

Comment: $0 = (-1)^3 + a(-1)^2 + b(-1) + 8 \Rightarrow 0 = -1 + a - b + 8 \Rightarrow a - b = -7$??

Comment: @HHuang - I do not see how that would matter as

$$x-y = c \iff -(x-y) = -c \iff y - x = -c$$

The integral thing seems right though. Based on the link in the OP, OP simply misread $12$ as $20$.

Comment: I’ve deleted that part, just momentarily forgot my properties of equality...